# ANDEngine : 3d rotation in Particle System

Tags: android, andengine, particles

Im using ANDEngine and wants to create confetti particle system.

But im unable to make flipping and rotation of confetti particle around z-axis
Since andengine is 2d engine, it doesnot support that.

However like in the following example , 3d rotation has been implemented for a single sprite:

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/Rotation3DExample.java

I want to do this for the particles. 
Am i missing something ? or do i hv to modify the particle system code.

Comment: What's the problem? Have you tried doing it for the particles? How to modify a library to add additional features is a bit too broad a question for this site. You should try adding the rotation and if you come up against a specific problem, as that question here.

Comment: I have done the rotation thing. But since it is the 2d engine , i cannot rotate on z axis, For rotation on z-axis, u have to modify your sprite's applyRotation method as i have mentioned in my link of andengine example. I want to create flipping effect on particles. which can only be done via 3d rotation

Comment: Actually it would be possible to simulate that with some very clever scaling.

Comment: I found this written smwhere in stackoverflow , i guess this is the same as ur telling :
A simple approach is to scale the Sprite as it moves back in distance. Just treat the scale property as a Z depth. But beware of Z-sorting (when items in depth overlap). In a simple game like paper toss this will not be a problem. But for example, if your object passes through a hoop, you will find it gets hard to manage.

Comment: Just use rotation like the example you linked shows:  `pGL.glRotatef(rotation, 0, 1, 0);` Where `rotation` is the amount to want to rotate and the last three values define the axis of rotation.

Comment: i know i can do so . but this effect can easily be setup for single sprite. This is wt im sayin .
For particle system ill have to modify code. im using BatchedPseudoParticleSystem and ill have to internal modificiations to library then . no other option then i think

Comment: You don't have to modify internal library. Just check any particle modifier. Inside the modifier you have access to the single sprite. Therefore you get the case you already know.

Comment: @Sm4 : im using batchedpseudoparticlesystem for optimum performance of particle system , which is using SpriteBatch instead of Sprite (SpriteBatch extends Generic shape class), therefore i cannot override applyRotation method , on it.If im wrong , kindly do correct me .

Comment: Sprites in Sprite batch simply share some OpenGL properties. They don't share transformations, you can do operations per entity. You can even do advanced stuff like this: http://android.kul.is/2013/09/tutorial-how-to-create-falling-snow-in.html